# Trying to access the memory of a non-kernel process via task_struct

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Currently I've written the following short code segment:

```
 struct task_struct *task_list;
 struct mm_struct *mm = task_list->mm;
```

My goal is to take a snapshot of the process during runtime (or while its state is waiting - whichever is easier).

[Process Address Soace Structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW19f.jpg)

Above I have included a graph of what mm_struct holds and I guess what I'm having trouble with is actually figuring out where the "vm_end" and "vm_start" sections of the struct are and if they actually contain the start/stop address I need in order to copy the memory of a process. Because vm_start and vm_end are a part of a struct called vm_region, not mm_struct. So, how do I take these values which are the beginning and ends of a memory region and how do I actually reference them in memory?

Would I need to access `struct vm_area_struct *mmap`? Since it is a list of VMA's?

Comment: Those addresses are in the process address space. see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/20778704/1216776